# Las imagenes no ocupan toda la pantalla

Tags: flexbox

Soy novato y estoy iniciando en este mundo, vengo con un problemita y es que no puedo lograr que las tarjetas ocupen todo el ancho de la pantalla, como ven en el código hice un contenedor y luego una caja para cada imagen. En la captura que estoy adjuntando no se visualiza bien el borde blanco del lado izquierdo.

**Código HTML**

```
<div class="container">
    <div class="card-1">
        <h3>Familia y menores</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card-2">
        <h3>Mediación</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card-3">
        <h3>Societario</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card-4">
        <h3>Migración</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card-5">
        <h3>Seguros</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card-6">
        <h3>Transito</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card-7">
        <h3>Laboral</h3>
    </div>
    <div class="card-8">
        <h3>Seguro de viajes</h3>
    </div>
</div>
```

**Código CSS**

```
.container{
    display:flex;
    flex-wrap:wrap;
    width:100%;
}

.container .card-1{
    width:330px;
    height:400px;
    background-image:url(./img/Familia\ y\ menores.jpg);
    background-size:cover;
    background-position:40%;
}
```

Captura de pantalla con el resultado:

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Puedes resolverlo de la siguiente manera:

```
<div class='container'>
    <div class='row'>
        <div class='img1'></div>
        <div class='img2'></div>
    </div>
    <div class='row'>
    </div>
</div>
```

Dentro del *div* de *class row* colocas tus imágenes y a en esta clase (*row*) usas la propiedad `justify-content: space-between;` puedes dejar las imágenes dentro de un div si tu quieres y te recomiendo mas usar un *width* y *max-width* para el manejo de los tamaños  de la imagen.

```
.row{
    justify-content: space-between;  
}
.img1{
    width:25% !important; 
}
```

Comment: en caso de ayudarte agradeceria marcaras mi respuesta como aceptada

Comment: Hola Josè gracias por tu respuesta, lo que pasa es que cada imagen lleva un texto encima de ella. Aqui te dejo un ejemplo en vivo para que veas a lo que me refiero, la caja se encuentra a mitad de pagina y si la inspecciones con la herramienta de desarrollador te das cuenta que usaron flex y el codigo va muy parecido al mio. https://www.lauretilaw.com

Comment: revisa la propiedad acabo de editar mi respuesta de esa manera se acomodan las imagenes

Comment: Gracias de nuevo, ya lo solucioné lo único que hice fue darle un width del 25% a cada caja, un abrazo amigo.

Comment: por nada, estamos para ayudarnos